# How to get current location in Windows Phone 7 on Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new in Windows Phone 7. I want to develop an application that tells current position (lat long) of device and highlight the current position in bing map that works on emulator because I dont have device for testing. Any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/GPS-Emulator

Comment: Thanks Marcom. ArgumentNullException was unhandled occured. No Source Available, Call Stack Location: System.ServiceMogel.dll!System.ServiceModel.AsyncResutl.End<System.ServiceModel.Chanels.ServiceChanel.SendAsyncResult>(System.IAsyncResult result) +0xa3bytes during debug on Emulator. What may be the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: you need to be more specific. How did you set up the emulator?

Comment: Thanks a lot. How to highlight a location in bing map in WP7 and to draw an arrow between current position and destination? Any idea?

Comment: It's better to close this question and start a new one since it is not directly related.

Answer (score 2):

CodePlex has a [FakeGPS](http://wp7gps.codeplex.com/) utility (just a .cs file).

Answer (score 0):

I just hard-code a known location:

```
if (location == GeoCoordinate.Unknown)
{
  // Use Palo Alto if we're running in the emulator.
  location_string = "&latitude=37.47&longitude=-122.12";
}
```