# Nearest location WP7

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-7.1

I want to make an application for Windows Phone 7.1 which determines the closest store out of 2 from my current location.
What i want to do in button.click event:

- Enable location services in phone
- Find current location
- Determine if current location is closest to point A or point B

I am making my application in C#.
The problem is, i can't find any code to do this.
Can anyone help me ?

**UPDATE**

I found some code that should retrieve my current location. Problem: the emulator doesn't seem to have a setting to enable the location services. So, I always get the same coordinates, which are the default ones (Lat: 47.64483 Long: -122.141197).
How can I enable the location services so I can get my real location ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into my old  [Maps_Examples_for_Windows_phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Maps_Examples_for_Windows_phone), specifically check the **My Map position** example, it has codes for getting position in WP7.

Then have a look into API docs for the [System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it does implement the **GetDistanceTo** function which tells you the distance to another location.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I have already found some code to retrieve my current location, BUT I don't know how to enable my location services in my phone settings. The emulator doesn't seem to have an option to enable this.. The result is that i always come to the dafault location of the phone, even in your example of "My Map Position". Any idea how I can turn on the location services so I get the right location ? –

Comment: have you chcked other questions on the topic, for example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016450/how-to-get-current-location-in-windows-phone-7-on-emulator

Comment: Well, i just found out it is not possible to retrieve actual data from an emulator, as you need a real device for it..
Thanks for your help anyway ;)

Comment: Then I suppose you need a device for testing, the method works at leadt